# Does using MonoTouch limit what you can do?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

If I was to develop a app using Monotouch (Xaramin.iOS), would it limit me and not allow me to do anything I could do using XCode and objective-c?

Comment: "you are only limited by your abilities"

Comment: @MitchWheat Cute quote. Irrelevant to programming.

Comment: @Yorye Nathan : read the answer below...and of course its relevant to programming. Don't be silly.

Comment: @MitchWheat You know, OOP, for example, is also a lot about limiting the user (programmer) - aka abstraction and encapsulation. I didn't say that he was limited in this case, I said the "only limited by abilities" is irrelevant to the programming world in general, and I stand behind it.

Comment: "I said the "only limited by abilities" is irrelevant to the programming world in general" - you are saying that noobs and gurus produce the same quality of code. erm, wrong!

Answer (score 1):

No, it has a native layer, so you can always drop back to interacting with the native API if it's not already surfaced in the MonoTouch API.

Comment: So I can use Apple's API along with the Monotouch API?

Comment: @user2350763, yes, the vast majority of said APIs are already surfaced in the MonoTouch APIs.  But if you find some that aren't, you can still access them, it just won't be very C-sharpy.

Comment: MonoTouch is essentially a set of C# wrappers around the native Obj-C API.  There shouldn't be any limitations compared to native development.